# insert mysql with case from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to insert my table in sql server from php. but i don't understand how to fix it form my query. is there any suggest that can help my query. is that correct that case statement can be put into php code like i did?

this is my code :

```
<?
 include "new.php";

 $ID_Person             =  $_POST['IDPerson']; 
 $Number_Phone_Person   =  $_POST['NumberPhonePerson']; 
 $Piority_Phone_Person  =  $_POST['PiorityPhonePerson']; 



  $response             =  array();

  if (isset($ID_Person)                 &&
isset($Number_Phone_Person)     &&
isset($Piority_Phone_Person)    
) 
  {

$query      = "INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone
                (
                ID_Person, 
                Number_Phone_Person, 
                Piority_Phone_Person

                )
                VALUES 
                (
                '$ID_Person',
                '$Number_Phone_Person', 
                '$Piority_Phone_Person
                CASE When PiorityPhonePerson = 1  Then 'Default' 
                ELSE 'Priority' + CONVERT (Varchar(5),Piority_Phone_Person) END');";


$hasil      = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$response);
    if($hasil)
{   

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

}   else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Eksekusi error.";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

   }    else 
   {
   $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Data gagal disimpan.";
   }
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
   ?>
```

i try any any suggest from google but can help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone
   (ID_Person, Number_Phone_Person, Piority_Phone_Person)
   VALUES ( '$ID_Person','$Number_Phone_Person','$emailid','$team_name' )";
```

Comment: what is your answer? it's not relevant what i'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

Your MySql Query is not proper, there is a syntactical mistake.

You can run this query directly to phpMyAdmin or Sql prompt, you will get error.

beacoze you have missed single quotes here
`'$Piority_Phone_Person
                CASE When PiorityPhonePerson = 1  Then 'Default' 
                ELSE 'Priority' + CONVERT (Varchar(5),Piority_Phone_Person) END'`

you can try below one and customise it according to your requirements.

`INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone
               (`

```
            ID_Person, 
            Number_Phone_Person, 
            Piority_Phone_Person

            )
            VALUES 
            (
            '$ID_Person',
            '$Number_Phone_Person', 
            '$Piority_Phone_Person
            CASE When PiorityPhonePerson = 1  Then `Default` 
            ELSE `Priority` + CONVERT (Varchar(5),Piority_Phone_Person) END');";
```

Comment: when i try it shows ,Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Default'.

Comment: INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone( ID_Person, Number_Phone_Person, Piority_Phone_Person )
VALUES (
'$ID_Person', '$Number_Phone_Person', '$Piority_Phone_Person CASE When PiorityPhonePerson = 1 Then `Default` ELSE `Priority ` + CONVERT (Varchar(5),Piority_Phone_Person) END'
);